# Unsubscribing from a published event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, widget, dom-events, publish-subscribe

I have a website that users can dynamically add widgets to.  These widgets use the Peter Higgins pub/sub plug-in to `$.(subscribe)` to an event that I `$.(publish)` from another 'core' module.

I have widgets in their own name space like this:

km.widget.name1,
km.widget.name2,
etc.

So the handles created by `$.(subscribe)` aren't global.

I do not know how to unsubscribe these widgets when the user decides to remove the widget from their custom page.

Also, how would I know which widget to unsubscribe from?

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this? We're going to have the same issue pretty soon. Would be interesting to see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem directly, but it may very well help you out.  [This is a recent blog](http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events) by Sam Clearman.  He describes a way to handle publish/subscribe events without using that plugin:

> jQuery custom events provide a built in means to use the publish subscribe pattern in a way that is functionally equivalent, and syntactically very similar, to Higgin’s pub/sub plugin: Just bind observers to document.

Doing it this way, you may be able to solve your current issues.

Comment: I had seen this article before and I'm just not convinced this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the pubsub plugin before, but I just glanced at [the source code](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js) and it looks like you can unsubscribe in exactly the same as as you subscribe, just using `$.unsubscribe(...)` rather than `$.subscribe(...)`.

Is this something you already know, and the problem is caused by your widget namespacing? I'm not *really* sure of what you mean by namespacing, anyway, since JavaScript doesn't support true namespaces (just objects - which I'm guessing is what you're using).